# Not being able to create as root

Tags: permissions, systemd, kernel, grub2, cgroups

```bash
$ sudo touch /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/baloo/memory.limit_in_bytes
touch: cannot touch '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/baloo/memory.limit_in_bytes': Permission denied
$ mount | grep cgroup
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
# echo 1024M >/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/baloo/memory.limit_in_bytes
bash: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/baloo/memory.limit_in_bytes: Permission denied
```

It's maybe due to cGroup/Linux refusing this parameter, but I don't understand why

Comment: Have you try to set value? `echo 100M >/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/baloo/memory.limit_in_bytes`

Comment: SameSameSameSame

Comment: ↑ what's the exact error from `echo 100M | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/baloo/memory.limit_in_bytes >/dev/null`? Please add it to your question

Comment: Have you first moved baloo to some cgroup. You could get valuable inspiration from https://gist.github.com/wd5gnr/9af32eff7fad5d4057b2698fb9606868

Comment: @roaima MC68020 gave an example using that

@ MC68020 my problem is about this script. So if this script "moved baloo to some cgroup", yeah, I done it

Comment: So you mean that your question here starts **after** having run that script (or having gone through each of its steps "manually") as root ?